# MVC componentization vs parallel data retrieval

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This question describes two approaches of solving the sophisticated architectural problem related to ASP.NET MVC. Unfortunately our team is quite new to this technology and we haven’t found any solid sources of information on this particular topic (except overviews where it’s said that MVC is more about separation than componentization). So as for now we are hesitating: whether our solution is appropriate or there is a different obvious way to solve this problem.

We have a requirement to make ASP.NET MVC-based design with componentization in mind. View engine Razor is also a requirement for us. The key feature here is that any level of controller’s nesting is expected (obviously thru `Html.Action` directive within `.cshtml`). Any controller could potentially obtain the data thru a webservice call (the final design can break this limitation, as it’s described below).

The issue is that the data must be obtained in async and maximum parallel fashion.  E.g. if two backend calls within the controllers are independent they must be performed in parallel.

At first glance the usage of [async MVC controllers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx) could solve all the problems. But there is a hidden caveat: nested controller must be specified within `cshtml` only (within a view). And a `.cshtml` view is being parsed after the original controller finished its own async execution. So all the async operations within the nested controller will be performed in a separate async slot and therefore not in parallel with the first parent controller. This is a limitation of synchronous nature of `.cshtml` processing.

After a deep investigation we revealed that two options are available.

1)  Have only one parent async controller which will retrieve all the data and put this data into container (dictionary or whatever). The nested controllers aren’t allowed to perform any backend calls. Instead of this they will have a reference to the initialized container with the results of all the backend calls. Bu this way the consumer of the framework must differentiate between parent and child controller which is not a brilliant solution.

2)   Retrieve all the data from backends within a special async HttpModule. This module will initialize the same container which will reside, for instance within HttpContext. Obviously all the controllers in such a case will not be allowed to perform any backend calls, but they will have a unified internal structure (in comparison with #1 option).

As for now we think that the option #2 is more desirable, but we are more interested in the solid community-adopted way to solve this problem in a real enterprise-level MVC projects.

Literally any links/comments are welcomed.

[UPD] A requirement of any level of nesting of controllers came from our customer which wants a system where fully reusable MVC components will be presented. And they could be combined in any sequence with any level of nesting - as it is **already done** in the existing webforms-based implementation. This is a business rule for existing app that the components could be combined anyhow so we're not targeted to break this rule. As for now we think that such a component is a combination of "controller+view+metadata" where "metadata" part describes the backend calls to be performed in the scenario 1 or 2.

Comment: Hi, have you considered doing load testing to see whether MVC 3 is up to the job?

Comment: we're trying introduce MVC to existing webforms-based project which is being constantly investigated by a performance team (Wcat, HP Load Runner, analyzing dumps etc). We revealed that asynchrony brings a great benefit to the existing app in terms of performance&scalability (see my comment to Adam's answer). So from the very beginning of MVC-related phase there is a requirement to make the data retrieval process asynchronous leveraging the maximum degree of parallelism. We see no huge issues with load testing if we achieve this goal. The question is how to achieve componentization as well

Comment: I know nothing of the specific tools you're using, but I'm concerned that both your choices prevent the controllers from doing the backend work themselves. ("nested controllers aren't allowed to perform any backend calls" and "all the controllers .. will not be allowed to perform any backend calls"). But controllers seem like the perfect place to put the backend calls -- and making each controller handle exactly one backend seems like a worthy goal.

Comment: Absolutely agree that according to ASP.NET MVC guidelines a controller is an appropriate place to perform backend calls. But how to handle the componentization (nested components which can retrieve data) and parallel data retrieval within one async slot then? We found no patterns regarding this so proposed to move the data retrieval within a separate async module or the parent controller. Entirely agree that it may seem a bit inappropriate way of using ASP.NET MVC but as for no we see no different options.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you considering async calls here? Keep in mind if your async calls are so the asp.net threads don't get all used up since the db is taking a while to return, as soon as new requests come in they too will go to the db, thus increasing the workload and in turn gaining nothing.

To be honest though, Im having a hard time following exactly what you have in mind here. Nested controllers for...?

"The key feature here is that any level of controller’s nesting is expected"
 I think I (we?) need a bit more information on that part here.

However, the warning on async still stands :)

Comment: We thought that making all the backend calls asynchronous will increase the scalability of the site since the managed thread will be released back to thread pool while waiting the response from a webservice. Moreover, our customer is too technical guy and is pushing the team to provide the async-based solution.

Comment: async will only help if there is truly something that will be helped by it. If the resulting thing that will be done async also has a limit and is hit often, then you gain likely nothing, may as well just increase the thread pool size. Theres a great post on this somewhere .. I'll try to find it.

Comment: this isnt the one I wanted - but still touches upon the point: http://aspnetresources.com/blog/sync_asynch_pages

Comment: Let me tell some words about our existing app in which we’re trying to introduce MVC. It’s a large enterprise project with a thick front end and a great number of relatively slow backends (SOAP or WCF services). Each service could be called in async fashion. Webfoms implementation uses async pages and async http handlers because of the results of a solid performance investigation. Cannot provide the exact digits but leveraging the async pattern in our case increased the overall performance very significantly. And obviously we're not using WaitOne() on async handle :)

Answer (score 0):

> E.g. if two backend calls within the controllers are 
>   independent they must be performed in parallel.

If they are truly independent you might be able to use asynch JavaScript calls from the client and achieve some degree of parallelism that way.

Comment: Some time ago (approx a year) AJAX was almost completely thrown away from our project because of the concern that on the first page load all the data must be rendered entirely on the side of a server. By this way the data retrieval parallelism (we have multiple backend calls on each page) is handled entirely on the side of a server leveraging high maintainable server-side frameworks (TPL analog). An of course, the issues with dynamic DOM manipulations on the retrieval of AJAX response were a very annoying concern for an end user. So here AJAX calls were abandoned